# How to run progress bar while executing the mysql query in java?

Tags: java, mysql, progress-bar

I want to delete duplicate record in my database table, and I do it in java by using this query

```
String sql = "DELETE e1 FROM tweet_after_preprocessing e1, tweet_after_preprocessing e2 WHERE e1.tweet = e2.tweet AND e1.tweet_after_preprocessing_id > e2.tweet_after_preprocessing_id"
```

The problem is when there are so many records in my database table, the process will take so long, and make my program look not curently running.

and I want to use progress bar to show progress of the executing, how can I do that?. I don't now the maximum and the minimum value, so how can i accessing the progress bar?.

Comment: i suggest waiting bar

Comment: waiting bar? how can i use it in java?

Comment: look at @Uwe plonus  answer.actually correct name is intermediate progress bar.you can't show how much persentage complete and how much left all you can do is showing that progress is still occurring

Answer (score 2):

You can create an indeterminate progress bar by setting the property indeterminate to true: [JProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate-boolean-).

Also it is wise to not execute long lasting work in the EDT but use a different thread for this.

Comment: Note that an indeterminate progress bar will not work unless he puts the sql on another thread.

Comment: this is correct answer .it's not possible to show normal progressbar .only possible thing is showing progress is occurring

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're doing all your work on the EDT, which is blocking your GUI. You need to do the loading on another Thread, so your GUI can still update, display, and respond to user input.

Once you have the work on another thread, then from that thread, you can post updates to the EDT using the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() method.

You could also look into the SwingWorker class, which handles some of that for you.

Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: i used swing worker, and actually my program is not stack, i can do anything else with it, i want to use progress bar to show the process of the executing.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question.

Jenkins uses the time of the last build to guess how long the current build will take to run.  So for example if the last time a build ran it took 10 minutes, and it is 5 minutes into a current build it will show that it is 50% complete.

You can do something similar.  Maybe query the DB first to see how many items need to be deleted and have a table of how long it will take for the amount of items being deleted and how many items are in the table.

Comment: ya i was thinking like that, but to updating the progress bar value i think i need to put the publish in loop, but i have no loop while i'm executing the query, so how?

Comment: use a thread for that.  one thread will run the DELETE and the other will manage the progress bar.  When the DELETE thread finishes it will update a shared object between the two threads to let the progress bar thread know that it is complete.  This is easy to do in Java using the various concurrency classes and methods it provides.

Comment: i don't know how to do it :(

Comment: this is what i've tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124143/how-to-run-progress-bar-in-java